# Moving entire shape to point on circle webgl

Tags: javascript, graphics, webgl

I have the following code trying to draw a wreath by putting stars on points on a circle. I  am able to draw one star, but when I try to draw a wreath it only draws one branch around the circle, or right now on one point on the circle. I know there is a problem with how I am nesting the modelViewMatrices I can't think of the proper way to go about doing the transformation. I need to draw the star and then translate the entire star.

```
   function DrawWreath()
    {
        var radius = 0.5;
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            var theta = i * 30;
            var x = radius * Math.cos(theta);
            var y = radius * Math.sin(theta);
            var t = translate(x, y, 0);
             if (modelViewMatrix) {
                modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, t) ;
             } else {
                modelViewMatrix = t;
             }
            modelViewStack.push(modelViewMatrix);
            DrawOneStar();
            modelViewMatrix = modelViewStack.pop();
        }

    }

function DrawOneStar()
{
    // draw the full star
    for (var i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
         r = rotate(72*i, 0, 0, 1);
         if (modelViewMatrix) {
            modelViewMatrix = mult(r, modelViewMatrix) ;
         } else {
            modelViewMatrix = r;
         }
         modelViewMatrix = r;
         DrawOneBranch();

    }
}

function DrawOneBranch()
{
    var s;

    // one branch
    s = scale4(1/16, 1/16, 1); 
    modelViewStack.push(modelViewMatrix);
    modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, s);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix));
    gl.drawArrays( gl.LINE_LOOP, 0, vertices.length);

    /*
    modelViewMatrix = modelViewStack.pop();
    //s = scale4(1/8, -1/8, 1);
    modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, s);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix));
    gl.drawArrays( gl.LINE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length);
    */
}
```

Comment: Obviously, how you manage your modelview matrices does not help to understands. You would better to pass matrices as argument in each sub-function instead of this pop/push method (inspired from old legacy OpenGL 1.0 book ?)... also think in transformation hierarchy (parent / children).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of issues with the code

- The code in `DrawOneStar` is rotating on the left

  ```
  mult(r, modelViewMatrix)    // ???
  ```

  Seems like you want this

  ```
  mult(modelViewMatrix, r)
  ```

  just like you did with `translate` and `scale`
- The code in `DrawOneStar` is not saving the matrix

  that means you either want to fix the code so it saves
  the matrix or, you want to rotate a fixed amount.

  As the code is now it's rotating 72, then rotating 72 + 144, then rotating
  72 + 144 + 216 because each time it's rotating the matrix it previously
  rotated
- The code in `DrawOneBranch` is not popping the matrix

  That line is commented out
- `theta` is using degrees

  Most math libraries use radians so this code is probably not doing
  what you expect

  ```
    var theta = i * 30;
    var x = radius * Math.cos(theta);
    var y = radius * Math.sin(theta);
  ```

  `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` require radians not degrees.
- The outer loop is only doing one iteration

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {   // ???
  ```

Other suggestions

- use a better math library. Whatever math library requires calling a `flatten` function to prepare the matrices to be usable by WebGL will be slower than one that doesn't. Also a library that takes radians for rotation and field of view means it will match the other built in math functions like `Math.cos` etc...
- Put a matrix in `modelViewMatrix` to start. Then you can remove all the checks for if there is a matrix or not
- When looping and computing a value consider using normalized numbers (numbers that go from 0 to 1) then computing other values based on that.

  For example the code has `theta = i * 30` in the outer loop and in the next loop there's `rotate(i * 72, ...)` but if you change the number of iterations then you also have to change those numbers to match.

  Instead first compute a value that goes from to 0 to 1 based on the loop. Example

  ```
  const numStars = 10;
  for (let i = 0; i < numStars; ++i) {
    const l = i / numStars;   // goes from 0 to 1
  ```

  Then use that value to compute the angle;

  ```
    const theta = l * 360;  // or l * Math.PI * 2 for radians
  ```

  Similarly

  ```
    const numRotations = 5;
    for (let i = 0; i < numRotations; ++i) {
       const l = i / numRotations;  // goes from 0 to 1
       rotate(i * 360, ....
  ```

  That way you can change `numStars` and `numRotations` easily and not
  have to change any other code

```js
function DrawWreath()
    {
        var radius = 0.5;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var theta = i / 10 * Math.PI * 2;
            var x = radius * Math.cos(theta);
            var y = radius * Math.sin(theta);
            var t = translate(x, y, 0);
            modelViewStack.push(modelViewMatrix);
            modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, t) ;
            DrawOneStar();
            modelViewMatrix = modelViewStack.pop();
        }

    }

function DrawOneStar()
{
    // draw the full star
    for (var i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
         var r = rotate(72, 0, 0, 1);
         modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, r) ;
         DrawOneBranch();

    }
}

function DrawOneBranch()
{
    var s;

    // one branch
    s = scale4(1/16, 1/16, 1); 
    modelViewStack.push(modelViewMatrix);
    modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, s);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix));
    gl.drawArrays( gl.LINE_LOOP, 0, vertices.length);
    

    modelViewMatrix = modelViewStack.pop();
    /*
    //s = scale4(1/8, -1/8, 1);
    modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, s);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix));
    gl.drawArrays( gl.LINE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length);
    */
}

function flatten(m) {
  return m;
}

function translate(x, y, z) {
  return m4.translation([x, y, z]);
}

function scale4(x, y, z) {
  return m4.scaling([x, y, z]);
}

function rotate(a, x, y, z) {
  return m4.axisRotation([x, y, z], a * Math.PI / 180);
}

function mult(a, b) {
  return m4.multiply(a, b);
}

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
const modelViewStack = [];
let modelViewMatrix = m4.identity();

const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 u_projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_modelViewMatrix;
void main() {
  gl_Position = u_projectionMatrix * u_modelViewMatrix * position;
}
`;

const fs = `
void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1); }
`;
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  position: {
    numComponents: 2,
    data: [
      0, 1,
      -.33, 0,
      .33, 0,
    ],
  },
});

twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
const scale = 1;
twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
  u_projectionMatrix: m4.ortho(
     -aspect / scale, aspect / scale, -1 / scale, 1 / scale, -1, 1),
  u_modelViewMatrix: m4.identity(),
});
const vertices = { length: 3, };
const modelViewMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(programInfo.program, "u_modelViewMatrix");
DrawWreath();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

One more thing, rather than manually computing a position on a cirlce you could use the matrix function for that as well, rotate, then translate

```js
function DrawWreath()
    {
        const radius = 0.5;
        const numStars = 20;
        for (let i = 0; i < numStars; ++i) {
            const l = i / numStars;
            const theta = l * Math.PI * 2;
            const r = rotateInRadians(theta, 0, 0, 1);
            const t = translate(radius, 0, 0);            
            modelViewStack.push(modelViewMatrix);
            modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, r);
            modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, t);
            DrawOneStar();
            modelViewMatrix = modelViewStack.pop();
        }

    }

function DrawOneStar()
{
    // draw the full star
    const numParts = 6;
    for (let i = 0; i < numParts; ++i) {
         const l = i / numParts;
         const r = rotateInRadians(l * Math.PI * 2, 0, 0, 1);
         modelViewStack.push(modelViewMatrix);
         modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, r) ;
         DrawOneBranch();
         modelViewMatrix = modelViewStack.pop();
    }
}

function DrawOneBranch()
{
    var s;

    // one branch
    s = scale4(1/16, 1/16, 1); 
    modelViewStack.push(modelViewMatrix);
    modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, s);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix));
    gl.drawArrays( gl.LINE_LOOP, 0, vertices.length);
    
    modelViewMatrix = modelViewStack.pop();
}

function flatten(m) {
  return m;
}

function translate(x, y, z) {
  return m4.translation([x, y, z]);
}

function scale4(x, y, z) {
  return m4.scaling([x, y, z]);
}

function rotate(a, x, y, z) {
  return m4.axisRotation([x, y, z], a * Math.PI / 180);
}

function rotateInRadians(a, x, y, z) {
  return m4.axisRotation([x, y, z], a);
}

function mult(a, b) {
  return m4.multiply(a, b);
}

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
const modelViewStack = [];
let modelViewMatrix = m4.identity();

const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 u_projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_modelViewMatrix;
void main() {
  gl_Position = u_projectionMatrix * u_modelViewMatrix * position;
}
`;

const fs = `
void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1); }
`;
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  position: {
    numComponents: 2,
    data: [
      0, 1,
      -.33, 0,
      .33, 0,
    ],
  },
});

twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
const scale = 1;
twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
  u_projectionMatrix: m4.ortho(
     -aspect / scale, aspect / scale, -1 / scale, 1 / scale, -1, 1),
  u_modelViewMatrix: m4.identity(),
});
const vertices = { length: 3, };
const modelViewMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(programInfo.program, "u_modelViewMatrix");
DrawWreath();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

You might find [these articles useful](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrix-stack.html)